# How to add an app to 'select application' menu

Tags: music, appmenu

i downloaded the gnome music app, but when i want to set it as the default music app, i'm not seeing the app in the 'select application' menu. I'm assuming there's a way to add it to the list of apps, but i don't know how. Thank you.

[image]